# Request processed on POST but fails on PATCH

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am using this code to upload an image (direct streaming into the database):

```
request.multipart.file('file', {}, async function(file) {                                                                                    
  const fileContent = await getStream.buffer(file.stream)                                                                                    
  photo.filecontents = fileContent                                                                                                           
  photo.type = `${file.type}/${file.subtype}`                                                                                                
})                                                                                                                                          
await request.multipart.process()
```

This works perfectly fine when on a POST HTTP request (**MyController.store()** method).

However, on a PATCH HTTP request (**MyController.update()** ),  the request always fails to process (I get a 500 HTTP code on the client side)

Both POST and PATH concern the same route  which I added in  `processManually`.

I spent one hour debugging this, the PATCH request reaches the server, everything works except when I un-comment  `await request.multipart.process()`.

If I leave only this in the `update()` method of my controller, the request fails to process too:

```
request.multipart.field((name, value) => {                                                                                                   
  product.name= value                                                                                                                        
})                                                                                                                                          
await request.multipart.process()
```

Did I set the correct headers on my PATCH request? Yes, the same as I did for POST.

The request also fails to process on PATCH but runs smoothly on POST

Any hints as why this is not working?